# angular CLI - Dynamically changing a checkbox from component doesn't actually change its state

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am using few check box in my form to control buttons + save the state. i will explain the issue with my code below.

```
<form role="form" name="layoutbutton" (ngSubmit)="save(layoutbutton.value)" #layoutbutton="ngForm" for="layoutbutton" ui-jq="validate">  
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="row">
<h5>PGM</h5>    
<div class="row-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="cam1c" name="cam1c" type="checkbox" (change)="cam1.hidden = !cam1.hidden" #cam1c="ngModel" [(ngModel)]=layoutbutton.cam1c>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="cam1c">CAM 01
<span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
<input class="onoffswitch-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="cam2c" name="cam2c" (change)="cam2.hidden = !cam2.hidden" #cam2c="ngModel" [(ngModel)]=layoutbutton.cam2c>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="cam2c">CAM 02
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
  <input class="onoffswitch-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="cam3c" name="cam3c" (change)="cam3.hidden = !cam3.hidden" #cam3c="ngModel" [(ngModel)]=layoutbutton.cam3c>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="cam3c">CAM 03
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

from my component i am dynamically setting the checkbox`$("#cam1c").prop('checked', true);`

After this if i submit the form i am not getting the checkbox value using the below code in the component. instead getting empty for checkbox.

```
save(data) {
this.submitted = true;
console.log("this.data",data.cam1c);
}
```

Comment: mixing `(change)`,`[(ngModel)]`, `value` and adding some jQuery on top of that is definitely not the way to go ! Maybe you should take a look at the [Forms guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) first.

Comment: (chnage) i use because to hide a dive.[(ngModel)] and value i tried to get this working. i thought jQuery is the easiest way to activate a property. @n00dl3 can you guide me how can i solve this.